# Form not showing data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

The database that i have made is largely successful within my workplace. However there is this wierd thing going on with one of my forms that wasnt doing it last week when it was last used. I havent done any updates to the form or VBA.

I have the form linked to the right table and I can enter data in. However after leaving the field it goes blank. Once I click back in the field I can see the data again. But when I leave it it hides itself again.
The picture attached is the form that I should be able to see the data.
My form is not is Data Entry mode.
Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. I have a whole shift dedicated to making updates and fixes on friday.

Thank you so very much!
[Brake Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdddK.png)

Comment: Suggest you post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Maybe leave a link here, of the forum question where you uploaded the database. I would like to take a look inside for you too.